# How to display record from listbox to data table or gridview?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linux

I have listbox1 and listbox2. When I click a button, the item from listbox1 transfers to listbox2.

My problem is, I only want to display on the gridview, listbox2 and not all the item from listbox1. I am using c#. I am thinking of creating a new dataset, data table then display it on a gridview, but I don't really know how to proceed.

Could someone please lend some help.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using gridview, it seems that you are using traditional asp.net webforms but not asp.net mvc (while u tagged it as asp.net mvc). 
If you are using webforms, you can try the CascadingDropDown control from [ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx)

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to this one. I already created it using listbox. is it really not possible for me to transfers my data from a listbox onto a gridview?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help a little.

you should first **create a dataset** (*named like dSet*), a **data table** (*named Customer*) and atLeast two Columns named CustomerID, CompanyName

in C#:

```
DataRow newCustomersRow = dSet.Tables["Customer"].NewRow();
newCustomersRow["CustomerID"] = "ALFKI";
newCustomersRow["CompanyName"] = "Alfreds Futterkiste";
dSet.Tables["Customer"].Rows.Add(newCustomersRow);
```

in VBNet:

```
Dim newCustomersRow As DataRow = dSet.Tables("Customer").NewRow()
newCustomersRow("CustomerID") = "ALFKI"
newCustomersRow("CompanyName") = "Alfreds Futterkiste"
dSet.Tables("Customer").Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
```

then bind it to your datagridview

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dSet.Tables("Customer")
```

Comment: but i already have rows and columns of data from the database displayed in listbox1. does this mean that because of modifying the data i want to display by using listbox2, i have to create another data table? can you please help me out on this... if i really have to create another data table, then this would mean that i have to use array and loop right?

Comment: you have to create a data table because it will be used as the datasource of the datagridview. you will only loop but instead of putting it in the array you will add new row in the data table.